# How do I crowbar mysql dates into mongodb using ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to port a list of wakeboard competition results stored in my legacy ruby on rails/mysql website into MongoDb for use with Meteor.

The route I'm taking is to mongoimport ruby generated json... here's example output so far for a competition:

```
[{
         "compnum": 7,
         "id": 165,
         "title": "AOD Stop 1",
         "description": "",
         "start_date": "2013-04-20T00:00:00.000Z",
         "end_date": "2013-04-20T00:00:00.000Z",
         "created_at": "2013-05-26T21:13:19.000Z",
         "country_id": 2,
         "photo_file_name": "",
         "location": "LDB WakeSchool",
         "entry": "",
         "manyotherfields": "",
         "divisions": []
     }]
```

The issue I'm having is that the dates (e.g. start_date) import into MongoDb as strings.  I'm using the mongoimport command with the jsonArray option:

```
mongoimport --host myserver:3001 -d meteor -c competitions comps.json --jsonArray
```

If I edit the json object using MongoChef I can change the type to date but I have hundreds of competitions so I want a way to create the dates in the correct format for import into mongodb.

Comment: The output string here is in the correct ISO format, so why can you just not wrap the output date in an object with relevant keys for [extended JSON syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date) like so `{ "start_date": { "$date": "2013-04-20T00:00:00.000Z" } }`? The `mongoimport` program will recognize that as a Date type and construct the document accordingly. Shouldn't be difficult to wrap that object in your ruby code doing the generation. Post the part of the generating code if you don't understand.

Comment: Should simply just work, no reason for it not to. If you had included that part of your ruby code I just would have typed in the patched lines as an answer.

Comment: Quick update to say thanks that did the trick... the [website](http://wakeboard.co.uk) is now migrated from Rails/Mysql to Meteor/MongoDb